# Keep Selection in JavaFX Textfield even if application is not focussed

Tags: css, javafx, textfield, highlight

**Background:**
I'm trying to implement a find/replace function for java-Fx table view. Whenever I find an occurance of the text to find, I switch the table view into edit mode and select the text found programatically in the textfield which is used during edit mode.

The focus in this situation remains in the modal find/replace dialog, so the selection in the textfield is not visible until I close the modal dialog.

**The problem:**
A textfield in Java-Fx shows it's selection only while it has the focus (as its standard behaviour). When the Java-Application loses focus the selection becomes invisible, when it gets the focus back the selection is visible again.

**Here is the question:**
Is it possible to keep the selection visible in a textfield though focus is lost?

**What I tried:**

I expected that CSS could help here:

```
textField.setStyle("-fx-highlight-fill: lightgray");
```

This changes the color of the highlighting but

- I wanted to keep the original color for the focussed Textfield
- I wanted to change the color from"invisible" to "lightgray" only for
  the non-focussed Textfield

What is the correct way?
Or is there a way to highlight text in a TableView without activating the TextField?

Thanks

Ingo

Answer (score 1):

If I am understanding correctly, the solution will be in the *modality* of your find/replace dialog.

It works for me when I do the following: Note that the java file this is written in extends Stage. If you are not extending stage then just call the methods on your find/replace stage.

```
owner = myApplicationStage;
initModality(Modality.NONE);//important for the solution!
initOwner(owner);
initStyle(StageStyle.UTILITY);
setScene(myFindAndReplaceScene);
stage = this;
stage.show();
```

This works perfectly for me, if you have any problems then hopefully I can help.

Comment: Thank you Cobbles. This is exactly my current workaround: I don'nt make my find/replace dialog modal and after I have found an occurance in the table (residing in the main stage) I set the focus to the main stage using table.requestFocus().
But this does not answer the question of what I really wanted to know: Even if the table (in edit mode) inside the main stage does not get the focus I want to show the selection inside the Textfield (e.g. in gray).. Any idea for that?

Comment: Sorry I don't quite understand what you mean, is it that you want the text in the table to be highlighted when the find/replace modal is on focus?

Comment: Exactly.
Interestingly enough the TableView (where textfield for editing resides in) has this behaviour: when it has the focus selected lines are blue, when another control (or stage) has the focus selected lines become gray (but still visible). I want this behaviour also for the Textfield...or another possiblity besides the Textfield to mark up the found text in a table view.